# Understanding and Leveraging @PostMapping for Resource Updates in Spring REST APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, post

I gone through experience developer spring boot code,
he used `@PostMapping` for **create**, **update**, **delete** resource.

with some Id check logic he decide whether resource should be created or update!

**Best practice and Considerations**

- What are the key factors to consider when deciding whether to use `@PostMapping` for updates, as opposed to the more conventional `@PutMapping`?
- Are there specific scenarios where `@PostMapping` is particularly well-suited for updates?

As far as know about REST recommendation:

```
@GetMapping - getting resources

@PostMapping - Creating resources

@PutMapping - Update resources, if not available create it

@DeleteMapping - Deleting resources

@PatchMapping - Partial update
```

does making post request make API **more secure** to use for create, update and delete.
OR is it good practice to use `@Postmapping` for secure API.

correct me if i am wrong.

here is some code sample:

```
@PostMapping("/createOrUpdate")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createResource(@RequestBody YourResourceType resource) {
 // use JPA findById to check it exist or not, and perform create or update logic
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/delete")
public ResponseEntity<String> createResource(@RequestBody YourResourceType resource) {
// use JPA findById to check it exist or not, and perform delete resource logic or
```

Comment: if you know what you are doing, you could probably do everything using GET and POST. However, for people who dont know what is going on, its more readable/understandable to use the other mappings

Comment: Rest is not protocol, It's a norms or suggestion.
As good practice we should use get,post,put,delete, as you mentioned 

"for people who don't know what is going on, its more readable/understandable to use the other mappings"

Does it cause anything when caching? if we use GET and POST for anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as per my REST API knowledge, REST gave

This isn't quite right.

[REST](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) says: we should have a [uniform interface](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5).  Which is to say, all resources should understand messages the same way.

HTTP says: this is the way that HTTP should understand messages.  That includes the semantics associated with each of the registered [HTTP methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) (GET, POST, PUT, and so on).

POST is the method token with the least constrained semantics - we are correct to use it anytime the semantics of more specific methods aren't suitable (see [Fielding 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)).

Note that the HTTP methods of the [transfer-of-documents-over-a-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain - the methods describe the manipulation of *resources* (aka "documents"), and don't necessarily align with the useful work that occurs as a side effect of manipulating the documents.

---

```
@PostMapping("/createOrUpdate")
@PostMapping("/delete")
```

Having a resource identifier for each kind of message is "fine"; it's essentially analogous to having a different resource for each form on a website.

It's not necessarily an ideal resource model; using a distinct resource for each kind of message makes [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons) harder.  But it will work, and it can be "good enough" in contexts where you don't actually care about caching.

Comment: So according to your answer, I can use @PostMapping for create and update resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use @PostMapping to create/update, and delete but this is not a good approach to do it.

I think this can break the coding standard.